# prevent resolveRtlPropertiesIfNeeded

Tags: android, android-layout

I trying to improve the speed of an app - traceview revealed a lot of resolveRtlPropertiesIfNeeded calls. Anyone knows how to get rid of them? I tried `android:supportsRtl="false"` in the manifest, but without any success.